# EXC_BAD_ACCESS StringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

What is wrong with this method?

```
- (void)randomInteger {
    count = (arc4random() % 5000) + 5000;
    NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
    if([countString rangeOfString:@"0"].location != NSNotFound && [countString rangeOfString:@"1"].location != NSNotFound && [countString rangeOfString:@"2"].location != NSNotFound && [countString rangeOfString:@"3"].location != NSNotFound) {
        score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
    } else {
        [self randomInteger];
    }
}
```

`count` is an integer declared using the following, `int count = 0;`. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on line number 3. I believe it happens on the second time through the method because if I comment out `[self randomInteger];` no error message is thrown.

Comment: `integer` isn't a real type. Show how `count` is really declared.

Comment: what is the type of `count`? `int` or something else?

Comment: Declared using the following, `int count = 0;`

Comment: Just to be sure - there is no asterisk (`*`) where you declare `count`?

Comment: BTW - why do you use recursion instead of a simple loop to generate the random number until it meets your condition?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have a need to calculate a random number from 5000 - 9999 but ignore any number with a 0, 1, 2, or 3 in any digit? Seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: @rmaddy Strange game. It's easier when any digit is 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may used too much stack space because recursion.

try this

```
- (void)randomInteger {
    while (true) {
        int count = arc4random_uniform(5000) + 5000;
        NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
        if([countString rangeOfString:@"0"].location != NSNotFound && 
            [countString rangeOfString:@"1"].location != NSNotFound &&
             [countString rangeOfString:@"2"].location != NSNotFound &&
              [countString rangeOfString:@"3"].location != NSNotFound) {
            score.text = countString;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also it would be better be to use `arc4random_uniform(5000)` instead of `arc4random() % 5000`.

Comment: Yup, that works! Curious as to why though...? I also edited your answer to work with my logic, `== NSNotFound`

Comment: it can take many iterations to generate the required number, and do it using recursion will end up using too much stack space and cause stackoverflow error.

Comment: @user3558410 There is a huge difference between a simple loop (in this answer) and a recursive loop (your original code). A recursive loop needs to recreate the stack on each iteration. Since your code could ignore hundreds of possible values before finding a match, the system runs out of stack space.